# KeyError when using torch.utils.data.Subset

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I'm getting the following error:

> KeyError: tensor(0)

I have created a custom dataset class as below:

```
class CovidDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
def __init__(self, file_type, transform=None):
    self.file_type = file_type
    self.transform = transform
def __getitem__(self, idx):
    img_name = self.file_type['filename'][idx]
    img = PIL.Image.open(img_name)
    label = self.file_type['label'][idx]
    if self.transform:
        img = self.transform(img)
    return img, label

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.file_type)
train_dataset = CovidDataset(train, transform=None)
```

I check that it can iterated using the following, and it works fine by outputing integers:

```
for idx, (data, img) in enumerate(train_dataset):
    print(idx)
```

I then try to create a subset of the original data using this, which works fine:

```
indices = torch.arange(3000)
train_dataset = torch.utils.data.Subset(train_dataset, indices)
```

However, when I try to iterate over the data using the previous line, it gives me the aforementioned error. What gives?

The full error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_20764/2967734632.py in <module>
----> 1 for idx, (data, img) in enumerate(train_dataset):
      2     print(idx)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataset.py in __getitem__(self, idx)
    469         if isinstance(idx, list):
    470             return self.dataset[[self.indices[i] for i in idx]]
--> 471         return self.dataset[self.indices[idx]]
    472 
    473     def __len__(self):

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_20764/4087125005.py in __getitem__(self, idx)
      5         self.transform = transform
      6     def __getitem__(self, idx):
----> 7         img_name = self.file_type['filename'][idx]
      8         img = PIL.Image.open(img_name)
      9         label = self.file_type['label'][idx]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    940 
    941         elif key_is_scalar:
--> 942             return self._get_value(key)
    943 
    944         if is_hashable(key):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _get_value(self, label, takeable)
   1049 
   1050         # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
-> 1051         loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
   1052         return self.index._get_values_for_loc(self, loc, label)
   1053 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    386                 except ValueError as err:
    387                     raise KeyError(key) from err
--> 388             raise KeyError(key)
    389         return super().get_loc(key, method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
    390 

KeyError: tensor(0)
```

Comment: What is the length of your original dataset?

Comment: The original data's length is 61781

Comment: Can you provide the full error backtrace?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error, I had solved it by changing the type of variable 'indices' from torch.TENSOR to LIST,and I think you can try the following code:

```
indices = torch.arange(3000).tolist()
train_dataset = torch.utils.data.Subset(train_dataset, indices)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).